# Is it possible to retrieve a history of the size of the RAM over time?

Tags: hard-drive, memory, ramdisk

I gave my PC to the service center. I remember that my computer had 8GB of RAM and when got back my computer has 4GB of RAM

Is it possible to retrieve a history of the size of the RAM over time?

Comment: No it is not, what did the service center do?

Comment: run `msconfig` > Boot > Advanced options to see if there are any memory limit set

Comment: If you bought the PC with its RAM as a complete system, you should have received a sales receipt. That's not a full proof you did not remove the 4GB Ram by yourself, but at least you may be able to make your claims look plausible to the service center.

Comment: The following sources might help if they exist/created before going to the service center.  - C:\Windows\Performance\WinSAT\DataStore\[timestamp] [type].Assessment (Initial).WinSAT.xml or - C:\windows\memory.dmp